# WooCommerce - Adding notice above products on Shop Home

Tags: plugins

I am trying to add a block of text above the products section on the base Shop page, but for some reason I am getting other titles above it, and I can't work out where to put it.

The block that I want to add is a simple div with some padding and some text.
I want to place it so that it appears underneath the main page title, which is Online Shop.

This is the page I'm talking about <strike>this</strike> (No longer active).

However, you'll notice that it's going underneath the Products title, which doesn't make sense.
I have tried to find the WooCommerce template file that creates that Product title, but I can't find it anywhere...

At the moment, that DIV block of text is in the woocommerce-template.php file, in the root of the Woocommerce plugin folder. 
(I'll move it to it's own folder within my theme when I've finished this, as I'm aware that it'll get overwritten with updates if I don't).

Can anyone point me to the right WooCommerce template file?

Comment: Turn on debugging and install the debug bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue, so if anyone is interested, I'll show what I did below.

I placed the aforementioned DIV in the WooCommerce plugin's wocommerce-template.php file, in the first function on line 29 (woocommerce_content). I placed it on line 46, so that it was in the 'else' part of the if statement that checks whether or not the page is a single product.
This means that it will only show up on main pages, not single product pages.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: To be clear, as you mention in your question, you'd first be copying the woocommerce template to your theme before modifying it